# How to use gcloud CLI to update firewall rules to append new IP addresses to source-ranges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, firewall

I've an existing firewall rule in my GCP project that allows incoming traffic to specific ports for a specific set of IP addresses/IP ranges. I want to update the source-range to include some more IP addresses/IP ranges. I've multiple such firewall rules.

I can update the firewall rules from UI but that's slow and requires multiple clicks. Instead I want to use gcloud CLI.

Here's the command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update <Firewall rule name> --source-range=<IP addr/range>
```

While these leaves the remaining attributes (for e.g. ports list) untouched (as documented), it overrides the existing source IP addresses/ranges. Is there a way to just append IP addresses/ranges to the existing source-ranges.

I can do a multi-step process/script where I first retrieve the list using:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="name=<Firewall rule name>" --format json
```

and create the updated list and then call the update command.

But assuming it would be a fairly common use-case to add/remove IP address ranges, I was wondering if there's a direct way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in 2 gcloud calls

```bash
# Get the firewall IP range
CURRENT_IP_RANGE=`gcloud compute firewall-rules describe your-firewall-name \
  --format="value[delimiter=',',terminator=','](sourceRanges)"`

# Add IP to the firewall IP range
gcloud compute firewall-rules update your-firewall-name \
  --source-ranges="${CURRENT_IP_RANGE}${IP}"

# Remove IP from the firewall IP range
gcloud compute firewall-rules update your-firewall-name \
  --source-ranges="${CURRENT_IP_RANGE#${IP},}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my script but I'm hoping there's a simpler/direct way:

```
gcloud auth login

p=<gcp-project-name>

x=<firewall-rule-name>

# The command below captures the existing source ip addresses/ip ranges
y=`gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="name=$x" --project=$project --format json | sed -n '/sourceRanges/,/]/p' | grep "\d" | xargs |  sed -e 's/ //g'`

z=<new-ip-addr-to-be-updated>

echo "Updating $x in $p with \"$y,$z\""

gcloud compute firewall-rules update $x --project=$p --source-ranges="$y,$z"
```